# Understanding bytePtrToString() from Golang pkg/net/interface_windows.go

Tags: string, pointers, go, byte, slice

I am trying to understand this code to convert from [16]byte to string:

```
// From: https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/net/interface_windows.go
func bytePtrToString(p *uint8) string {
    a := (*[10000]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(p))
    i := 0
    for a[i] != 0 {
        i++
    }
    return string(a[:i])
}

// Type of ipl.IpAddress.String is [16]byte
str := bytePtrToString(&ipl.IpAddress.String[0])
```

I mean, what is the reason for the pointer magic? Couldn't it be written simply as follows?

```
func toString(p []byte) string {
    for i, b := range p {
        if b == 0 {
            return string(p[:i])
        }
    }
    return string(p)
}

// Type of ipl.IpAddress.String is [16]byte
str := toString(ipl.IpAddress.String[:])
```

Comment: It looks like this module does Windows syscalls whose return values include "C strings", i.e., C `char*`s that point to [null-terminated strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) without explicit lengths. The `bytePtrToString` code looks like a reasonable way to turn one of those (of length up to 10000) into a Go string.

Comment: Yeah, I see what bytePtrToString() is trying to achieve... I just don't understand why it uses pointer instead of plain slices like I sketched above (or even plain arrays).

Comment: My suspicion is that at least one of the Windows syscalls in the module isn't actually returning a byte slice of the correct `len`, so that func has to make up a big length and look for the `\0`. It may be that in `IpAddress.String`'s case it's not needed because the length is bounded, but for some other returned value it is. I'm not on Windows so it's hard for me to dig further; sorry for the inconclusive babble.

Comment: If you want to know for sure, you could copy `net/interface` code to a `mynetinterface` package and sprinkle `fmt.Println`s around in this file to see if the structs returned by the Windows API have any bare `*byte`s or slices with fake `len`s of 0 or 1 or other oddities that would explain the need for `unsafe` gymnastics.

Answer (score 0):

No, it could not be written as you propose.
You forget what []byte is not array of bytes. Its slice of bytes. 
In memory slice is just structure which has pointer to buffer (array of bytes, which will hold data) and some information about array size.

```
a := (*[10000]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(p))
```

this code convert byte pointer to array of bytes.
In go array of bytes - its just bytes, like in C. Nothing more.
So if you will declare array of bytes:

```
var buffer [256]byte
```

Go will allocate exactly 256 bytes, array don't even have length. Length of array is part of its type, and only compiler have information about array length. 
Whats why we can convert byte pointer to array. Its basically the same.

```
i := 0
for a[i] != 0 {
   i++
}
```

Here we just find the end of null terminated string.

```
return string(a[:i])
```

Here we use slicing operation to create a string. In Go string is basically constant slice, so it will point to the same memory address as original byte pointer.

This two articles will help you understand this topic a bit better:

- http://blog.golang.org/slices
- http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: Did you notice the call str := toString(ipl.IpAddress.String[:]) is slicing the full [16]byte array into a 16-byte slice? Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Agree with @Everton. To justify `unsafe` tricks in the module I'd need to see source strings with unknown length (e.g., a bare `*byte` in some struct) or too-short lengths (e.g., `len(s)==1` but string is really 100 bytes).

Comment: @Everton, since the API call around which that pointer magic is involved supposedly returned a pointer to some volatile memory location, Go side has to *copy* that memory, and that’s what type-conversion of `[]byte` to `string` does (one of very few places in Go where type-conversion has hidden `O(n)` cost).

Comment: @everton, the slice trick you're puzzled about is documented [here](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/cgo) -- see the "Turning C arrays into Go slices" section.

Comment: @kostix, what I think is confusing is that there's already a reasonable slice in the calling code, and you could seemingly do the conversion to string (and the copy that that implies) just using that slice, without `unsafe` tricks. I have to wonder if the `unsafe` tricks are either vestigial or needed by other code else in the package where a `*uint8` is returned raw by the API or the slice length is wrong.